# Highcharts-How to align shared tooltip on the top of column in multiple series column chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I am using highcharts.js for multiple series column chart and I want to show the shared tooltip on the top of group of column(It should take the highest column length) 
So far I have tried this https:[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vansha/0ru7zh3w/).

```js
$(function() {

  chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      type: 'column',
      plotBorderColor: '#CDCDCD',
      plotBorderWidth: 1,
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: "category"
    },
    yAxis: {
      endOnTick: true,
      startOnTick: true,
      tickInterval: null,
    },
    tooltip: {
      useHTML: true,
      borderRadius: 0,
      borderWidth: 0,
      shadow: false,
      followPointer: false,
      hideDelay: 0,
      shared: true,
      enabled: true,
      backgroundColor: "none",
      positioner: function(labelWidth, labelHeight, point) {
        var tooltipX, tooltipY;
        var chart = this.chart;
        tooltipX = point.plotX + chart.plotLeft - 20;
        if (point.negative)
          tooltipY = point.plotY + chart.plotTop + 20;
        else
          tooltipY = point.plotY + chart.plotTop - 30;
        return {
          x: tooltipX,
          y: tooltipY
        };
      },
      formatter: function() {

        var templateHtmlString = "";
        templateHtmlString += '<div class ="ttContainer">';
        $.each(this.points, function(index, item) {
          templateHtmlString += '<div class = "ttItem">';
          templateHtmlString += item.y;
          templateHtmlString += '</div>';
        });
        templateHtmlString += '</div>';

        return templateHtmlString;
      }
    },
    series: [{
      "color": "red",
      "data": [5,-1,17,9,8,19,-2,8,10],
      "name": "ABCD"
    }, {
      "color": "Green",
      "data": [8, -7,2,11,28,14,-3,8,-1],
      "name": "XYZ"
    }]
  });
});
```

```css
.ttItem {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

but it doesn't work when height of second column is greater than the first column. Please suggest how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I figured out the solution myself.I have updated the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vansha/0ru7zh3w/4/).
I have modified the tooltip.positioner function to set the tooltip position.

```
         positioner: function(labelWidth, labelHeight, point) {
          var tooltipX, tooltipY;
          var chart = this.chart;
          var hoverPoints = this.chart.hoverPoints;
          var y = 0;
          var x = 0;
          var totalColumnWidth = 0;
          var deltaX = 0;
```

**this.charts.hoverPoints** contains the array of point object being hovered in case of multiple series chart.I loop through each point object in hoverpoints array.

plotY- y coordinate value of each column/point

barX - Starting x coordinate of each column/point

pointWidth - Width of each column/point

I have set the x as start of first point and y as the lowest plotY value among all points(lowest plotY means highest column)

```
          $.each(hoverPoints, function(index, hPoint) {
            var plotY = Math.ceil(hPoint.plotY);
            if (index === 0) {
              x = Math.ceil(hPoint.barX);
              y = plotY;
            }
            totalColumnWidth += Math.ceil(hPoint.pointWidth);
            if ((plotY > y && point.negative) || (plotY < y && !point.negative)) {
              y = plotY;
            }
          });

       delta = (totalColumnWidth - labelWidth) / 2
```

delta variable used to center align the tooltip.
           tooltipX = x + chart.plotLeft + delta;

If column is on positive axis then add labelHeight so that tooltip wont overlap on column.

```
          if (point.negative)
            tooltipY = y + chart.plotTop;
          else
            tooltipY = y + chart.plotTop - labelHeight;
          return {
            x: tooltipX,
            y: tooltipY
          };
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could find the total height of y-axis and compare that with the points in the tooltipPos in hoverPoints.

```
$('#div_id').find('.highcharts-container').find('.highcharts-root').find('.highcharts-plot-background').attr('height'));
```

This way you could position each tooltip accordingly.